# How to format the output of "wpa_cli scan result" command in a well aligned column?

Tags: wifi, columns, text-formatting, printf, wpa-cli

How would you suggest to align all SSID in one single column in the `wpa_cli scan_result` command?

To be clear, I want to transform this output

```
# wpa_cli scan_results
d8:fb:5e:a5:38:20   [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS] zdn-11878
08:96:d7:7e:d8:12   [WPA-PSK-TKIP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS] Ubeda 5
6c:3b:e5:4b:ea:00   [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS] HP-Print-
```

Into this one

```
# wpa_cli scan_results
d8:fb:5e:a5:38:20   [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS]                   zdn-11878
08:96:d7:7e:d8:12   [WPA-PSK-TKIP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS]     Ubeda 5
6c:3b:e5:4b:ea:00   [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS]                        HP-Print-00-Photosmart 5520
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `column` to format the output:

```
wpa_cli scan_results | column -t
```

On the latest kernel releases , the output of the `wpa_cli` is already formatted without adding any options.